# WSO2 AM API DOCS - Is there a way to use swagger as API Documentation in DevPortal?

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

The company that i work for is developing an API to allow an integration with our applications. We're using WSO2 AM as our gateway. I hava to document the API and they want me to use WSO2 devportal to do so. But the problem is that they also wanna use Swagger to create this documentation. Is there a way to add Swagger in the API Docs?

Comment: The swagger definition of the API can be downloaded from Overview and Try Out pages in the Developer Portal.

Comment: By default it allows the following file formats - "pdf", "txt", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "odt", "ods"

Comment: Maybe you can host the swagger in some location and use that url in the docs

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be, you can add document type of `Markdown` and add the swagger content as code.

So it can be viewed from Devportal as shown below:

[image]